# unambiguous grammar that produce equal number of a and b

Tags: formal-grammars, ambiguity

is there any **unambiguous grammar** on alphabet={a,b} that can produce strings which have equal number of a and b (e.g. "aabb" , "baba" , "abba") ?

Comment: Are we speaking of context-free grammars? I would start from devising a CFG (possibly ambiguous) for that language... can you provide us one such grammar?

Comment: yes we have context-free grammar for that 
S->aSbS|bSaS|Ɛ
but problem is that grammar is  ambiguous

Comment: You should be able to build a deterministic automaton that recognizes it. Then, using the algorithm described in a proof that deterministic implies unambiguous, you should be able to get the grammar you want.

Comment: Linked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388367/cfg-for-language/388395#388395

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: @xavierm02. True, in theory, but while it's easy to build a PDA for the language, the usual algorithm to go from the PDA to a CFG in this case would be so complex that I'd never attempt it without mechanical aid. Fortunately, your answer avoids this step.

Comment: Another solution: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74467/finding-a-unambiguous-grammar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with $S\to aSbS\mid bSaS\mid \varepsilon$ is that you're just making sure you match each $a$ with a $b$ (where we consider an $a$ and a $b$ to be matched iff they appeared during the same derivation step).

To ensure non-ambiguity, you must add a constraint on the matching to ensure that it is unique (while maintaining its existence). One way to do that is to make sure you match the first $a$ (resp. $b$) after your $b$ (resp. $a$) that hasn't been matched yet.

So you'd get something like $$
S\to aB S\mid bA S \mid \varepsilon\\
A \to a \mid b \square\\
B\to b \mid a\square$$

The idea is the following:

- You want $S$ to generate words with as many $a$ as $b$s. At any points you can stop with the $S\to \varepsilon$. If you do add an $a$ with $S\to aBS$, then you need to add a $b$ later, and you put a $B$ to remind you of that, and then you continue with another $S$. The same things applies for $S\to bAS$.
- If you have an $A$, it means that you are one $a$ short. If you read an $a$, everything is fine and you've got nothing else to do. But if you read a $b$, you are now two $a$s short. I left a $\square$ for you to fill to encode that.
- $B$ works like $A$.

---

Solution :

> You are two $a$s short so you are twice one $a$ short: $A \to a \mid b AA$. Similarly $B\to b\mid aBB$

---

For the proof, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388367/cfg-for-language/388395#388395) where $a,b,A,B$ are replaced with $0,1,O,I$ and your language is generated by $E$.

Answer (score -1):

The ambiguity of the above grammar can be resolved as

S->aBS/bAS/ε
A->a/bAA
B->b/aBB

Comment: What's the difference from the other answer?