# unambiguous equivalent grammar

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, ambiguity

There is a grammar G given:

```
    S->XaX
    X->aX|bX|eps
```

I just replied to the first question that was about showing that this grammar is ambiguous. The second question is to find an unambiguous equivalent grammar of this grammar given. I don't really know how to do it or from where to start. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you seen: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74467/finding-a-unambiguous-grammar ?

Answer (score 1):

Your language consists of all words over $\{a,b\}$ which contain $a$. This is a regular language, and so it has an unambiguous regular grammar - essentially a DFA - which is not so difficult to construct for this language. Regular grammars constructed from DFAs are unambiguous, so this would be an unambiguous grammar for the same language.