# Non-deterministic Turing Machine recognizing a context-free Language

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, nondeterminism, algorithm-design

This question is taken from an exam of a Computer Theory Course.

> Describe how a NON-Deterministic Turing Machine with two tapes recognize the language generated from the grammar: $ S \rightarrow SS | (S) | )S( | \epsilon $.

- Tape 1: Read-Only & monodirectional
- Tape 2: Read and Write, bidirectional

**My guess:**

Example of string generated by this language: $w_1 = ()())($  $w_2 = )()($ 
$w_3 = )))((()($

I think that the Turing Machine should recognize strings such that for every open (close) parenthesis there is another close (open) one.

*With non-determinism*: I need to guess where a portion of string is generated by a valid production, but i have some troubles to formalize this concept. Any hints?

For the string $w_2$:
One configuration in the computation tree would be $)(q_c)($ where $q_c$ identify the starting point of the production.

Comment: Hint: use the second tape to store the number $diff = \#_( - \#_)$; i.e. the (possibly negative) difference between the $($s and $)$s encountered so far. At each new symbol guess ... . At the end of the input check if $diff$ ...

Comment: @Vor Do we have to guess at each new symbol? Just checking at the end would do? [unambiguous grammar that produce equal number of a and b](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64569/unambiguous-grammar-that-produce-equal-number-of-a-and-b)

Comment: @HendrikJan: you're right ... storing $diff$ seems powerful enough to make  nondeterminism useless.

Comment: Please state your question in the title ... this will be helpful for those searching for questions relevant to their own.

Comment: @HendrikJan I know that at the end, on the working tape should be written "0" but i can't figure out how precisely works the non-determinism here